# How can I implement login with email address or username using Parse.com?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Until now we have checked the login credentials with UserName and password using following syntax.

***`logInWithUsernameInBackground`***

```
 [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:[UsernameField.text lowercaseString] password:PasswordField.text block:^(PFUser* user, NSError* error){
```

But now my requirement is that:

**User must need to login with any one of both email and UserName**.

And we need to check with **username / email and password**

How can this be achieved?

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 16):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:UsernameField.text];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (objects.count > 0) {

            PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *username = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
            [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:PasswordField.text block:^(PFUser* user, NSError* error){
            }];
        }else{
            [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground: UsernameField.text password:PasswordField.text block:^(PFUser* user, NSError* error){
            }];

        }


    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 / 4**

Metin Say's answer converted to Swift.

```
static func signIn(username: String, password: String, onSuccess: @escaping ([PFObject]) -> (), onError: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "User")
        query.whereKey("email", equalTo: username)
        query.findObjectsInBackground(onSuccess: { (objects) in
            if (objects.count > 0) {
                guard let object = objects.first as? PFUser, let username = object.username else{
                    return
                }
                PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: username, password: password) { (user, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        onSuccess(objects)
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: username, password: password) { (user, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        onError(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        onSuccess(objects)
                    }
                }
            }
        }, onError(error.localizedDescription))
    }
```