# Login Screen with Username and Password via Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6, pfuser

I have the Parse SDK all set up and working for my practice app. The tutorial I was following had a log in and sign up using a `UIAlertController`. I want to have a log in screen but I am new to iOS development.

I have a `User` class in my Parse data and I want to connect a `userNameTextField` and `passWordTextField` to my `LogInViewController` class with my StoryBoard. I also will have a `loginButton` of type `UIButton` on the bottom of those text fields.

This is my function in my `LogInViewController` but the class will not show the methods of PFUser.

```
func login() {


    PFUser.logInWithUserNameInBackground(userName.text, password: passWordLabel.text){
        (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
        if((user) != nil){
            println("Login Successful")
            var installation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            installation.addUniqueObject("Reload", forKey: "channels")
            installation["user"]  = PF.currentUser()
            installation.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector:nil)
        }
        else{
            println("Login Failed")

        }
    }
```

I get this error `PFUser.type does not have a member named loginuser with background` which is odd because my `UIAlertController` in my app works fine when I used this method. I do not know if this should go my `LoginViewController` or called within my apps main swift file.

I am a little lost if you understand what I am asking for have been through the same issues and respond thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you queried to get the user details before logging in? Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18595207/3615320