# Email Login with Parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I am adding the option to log in via email instead of username. I am using Parse as backend. I changed the "username" string to "email" in my function but the log with username is still active. I can't seem to log in with email.

Also, if you have an advice on how to set conditions for email to be valid (as in what characters are allowed, please let me know)

```
    var email = self.emailField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text


    if (count(email.utf16) < 4 || count(password.utf16) < 5 ) {

       var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Email/Password too short", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
    else {
        self.actInd.startAnimating()


        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(email, password: password, block: { (user, error) ->
            Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((user) != nil) {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("logconfirmed", sender: self)

            }else {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Please enter a valid Email and Password", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()   
            }
        })   
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implement login with email address or username using Parse.com?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485268/how-can-i-implement-login-with-email-address-or-username-using-parse-com)

Comment: I am actually looking to add email instead of username not both at the same time.

Comment: Just copy the input from the users email to their username?

Answer (score 0):

It think this is what you are looking for.

[How can I implement login with email address or username using Parse.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485268/how-can-i-implement-login-with-email-address-or-username-using-parse-com)

Basically the Parse User object uses a username but you can set it up to use a email address in there or also keep a username and add an email column and then check that column on login

Comment: When you can give an answer as “Maybe the answer to this other question will help you” be aware of a possible duplicate. If you think the question is a duplicate (which I suspect of this question and the question you posted) please flag it to help other users find the right answers faster. And yes, Objective-C and Swift answers can (and should be) seen as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set:

user.username = emailTextField.text

user.email = emailTextField.text

Then whatever the username would be, you could do:

user["Username"] = usernameTextField.text

Thats the easiest way to do it.