# Implementing email or username to login using swift with Parse as backend

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

This is my first time programming an app and any help is deeply appreciated. I am implementing a feature where the user can use their email or username to login to their account. The problem is that the document on parse.com only provides a way to login using a username, but I want to also use an email address to login.

I found a link that will definitely help me solve this problem:
[How can I implement login with email address or username using Parse.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485268/how-can-i-implement-login-with-email-address-or-username-using-parse-com)

The only problem I am running into when looking at this solution is that it is in Objective-C and I want it in Swift. I am still new at Swift and my knowledge of Objective-C is not too great and it is hard for me to convert this code to Swift.

But specifically, this is the part of the code I am having a hard time converting:

```
PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *username = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
```

I think everything else is straight forward and I can convert the rest. Any help with converting this code to Swift would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to ask a more specific question.  For example, which part of the code are you actually having trouble converting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your swift code from that objective-c code:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("email", equalTo: UsernameField.text)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                if objects.count > 0 {
                    let object = objects[0] as! PFObject
                    let userName = object["username"] as! String
                    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName, password: self.PasswordField.text, block: {
                        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


                    })
                } else {
                    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(self.UsernameField.text, password: self.PasswordField.text, block: {
                        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


                    })
                }

            }else{

                println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
            }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse has all of this in their iOS documentation. It defaults to Objective-C, but you can press the little `Swift` tab in a block to see the Swift equivalent.

[It can all be found here.](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users) Check out the Users/Queries sections.

*Example:*

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if user != nil {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  } else {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
}
```